# Search builder does not display date picker for contacts

Tags: search-builder

I am running Drupal 7.61 and CiviCRM 5.8.0. I have recently upgraded from 5.3.1 and when I use search builder to locate contacts using created date the date picker does not display. (See attached video link). If I use search builder to find an individual using their birth date the date picker functions correctly.

I have not made any configuration changes to CiviCRM in the upgrade process.

[Video showing date picker issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eEcirO-AWDk6o2ddIFBhkQ6GuOJQIkPF/view?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot from Demo Site](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jALyk2SSUR29GM1YUWXRwe4AF6GT3WL5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: seems not to pop-up for Date Received for Contribution either on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - also i compared with a 5.3.1 site and not seeing date picker there so not sure if you are suggesting this is a regression or not, but i suggest it is not..

Comment: It worked fine on 5.3.1 - I used it every day to locate Contacts created after a certain Created Date and it worked just fine. It does work if you search for an Individual's Birth Date.

Comment: but Birth Date works on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard if you click in the date cell you get a calendar

Comment: No it doesn't - I will add a link to the relevant page in the demo site (which is running 5.10.alpha1 and in Spanish which is not my first language!) in the original post and it shows that the date picker does not display. In fact it operates exactly as in my installation of 5.8.0.

Comment: my apologies - i skim read and thought you were saying that it also didn't work on birth date.

Comment: I also misread stuff, this time in Peter's comment above. Individual Birth date works OK on 5.3.1 and 5.8.0. It is Contact's Created Date that works on 5.3.1 but not on 5.8.0 as shown in Peter's answer below.

Comment: Martin - open a ticket if you want us to patch on your site so you can QA

Answer (score 3):

There was a small bug introduced in the last version where the calendar icon didn't show up in search builder date fields, but the actual datepicker still works fine.

The screenshots and videos are misleading, as they use *Contact:Created Date* as the example field - this is actually *not* a date field (despite the name) it is a *Timestamp* which doesn't work with the datepicker widget, unfortunately, so I don't believe this is a regression.

Edit: I stand corrected. Previous versions *did* provide a datepicker for timestamp fields, however it didn't work very well since it didn't allow you to specify time. I've created a fix to restore the datepicker and add a timepicker for those fields: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13249

Comment: Thx Coleman - can you clarify. The screenshot in my answer shows there was a Calendar picker in 5.3.1 that worked but you seem to be saying it doesn't work with a datepicker widget. - i added more images to my answer

Comment: Err, I guess it sort of works, except it won't with the `=` operator as the date entered is less precise than the timestamp. Maybe for timestamp fields we should be presenting a date+time widget for clarity.

Comment: Ok I think I've fixed it! Datepicker now works on both Date and Timestamp fields!
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13249

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am seeing on dmaster compared to a 5.3.1 site

[image]

seems like a regression. needs an issue opening.

More from 5.3.1

The datepicker in action

[image]

and the outcome

[image]

Comment: Will I raise the issue or will you do that?